# MongooseError - Operation buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I have following code for model.

```
import { DatabaseServer } from './database-server';
import { ProjectGroup } from './project-group';
import { ProjectUser } from './project-user';
import { prop, getModelForClass, ReturnModelType, modelOptions } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { defaultTransform, ModelBase } from '../general/model-base';
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';
import { BeAnObject } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/types';

export class Datasource extends ModelBase {

  @prop()
  databaseServer?: DatabaseServer;
  @prop()
  databaseServerId?: ObjectID;
  @prop()
  datasource?: Datasource[];

  @prop()
  name?: string;
  @prop()
  projectGroups?: ProjectGroup[];
  @prop()
  projectUsers?: ProjectUser[];

}

const DatasourceModel = (
  connection: Connection,
): ReturnModelType<typeof Datasource, BeAnObject> => {
  return getModelForClass(Datasource, {
    ...defaultTransform,
    ...{
      existingConnection: connection,
    },
  });

};
export { DatasourceModel };
```

And I am using above model as following.

```
await DatasourceModel(await this.masterContext).find({})
```

Where mastercontext is defined as below.

```
import {
  Connection,
  createConnection
} from 'mongoose';

export class MasterContext {
  get context(): Promise<Connection> {
    if (!this.m_context) {
      this.m_context = createConnection('mongodb://localhost/Master', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      });
    }

    return this.m_context;
  }
  private m_context: Promise<Connection>;
}
```

I am getting error as following.

`Operation datasources.find() buffering timed out after 10000m`

If I change class name from `export class Datasource` to any other name (e.g. `export class Datumsource`) then error is not throwing.

So is `Datasource` reserved keyword in MongoDb or Mongoose or Typegoose?

Comment: at least in typegoose it is not reserved

Comment: could you maybe include the versions used (typegoose, mongoose, typescript) and the compiler (tsc / babel / ts-node)

Answer (score 1):

from what i know, this error means that the connection is not connected, so the command (`find`) has an timeout

i also would recommend to either cache the `DatasourceModel` or only run the function once (the connection does not need to be connected to create an model, it only needs to be connected to do commands (like `find`))
so if you have an global connection, you should simply remove the function and just run `getModelForClass`, but if you have an "local" connection (like from an class property), then you should cache it there, example:

```
// i think this way of defining stuff is common in nestjs?
class Dummy {
  public connection: mongoose.Connection;
  public model: mongoose.Model;

  constructor(connection: mongoose.Connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
    this.model = getModelForClass({ ...otherGlobalStuff, existingConnection: connection });
    // or when wanting to use your function
    this.model = DatasourceModel(connection);
  }
}

// and if for one file only
let model = DatasourceModel(connection);
```

Some other notes:

- if you want to use arrays in typegoose, you need to manually define the type with the `type` option, [look here on why](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/prop#array-options)
- only the `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` type should be used for an `ObjectId`

Comment: Somehow. When I change model name it is working. So connection has no issue as it is working with DatasourceS model and also await before DatasourceModel is for find, not model itself.

Comment: then sorry, i have no clue - at least in typegoose the name `Datasource` (any case) is not reserved or used